# Windows Server sometimes has wrong date

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, scheduled-task, time

Having a Windows Server 2016 (hosted at Amazon AWS EC2) that is running successfully for years.

Since some month I'm experiencing that the Scheduled Tasks (e.g. a task that is configured to run daily) are not being executed. No error message in the task history. No entry in the Event Log. Nothing.

The tasks simply do not run, and in the "Next Run Time" column is a date in the future, e.g.  tomorrow. When looking again tomorrow, the same picture: not ran any tasks, "Next Run Time" points to the future, again.

Here is another example of what the odds in my system time look like:

[image]

Above, a screenshot of Windows Update shows that an update of SQL Server that I've installed at 5th of *February* 2022 actually is erroneously being shown as installed at 5th of *March* 2022. One month in the future.

I've just called this in the command line:

```
C:\>w32tm /query /status
```

Which printed this result:

```
Leap Indicator: 0(no warning)
Stratum: 4 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
Precision: -6 (15.625ms per tick)
Root Delay: 0.0096024s
Root Dispersion: 0.0493815s
ReferenceId: 0x28779426 (source IP:  40.119.148.38)
Last Successful Sync Time: 08.02.2022 08:41:13
Source: time.windows.com,0x8
Poll Interval: 10 (1024s)
```

Nothing suspicious looking to me.

I've also checked for viruses without any positives. I've also run the ["MRT" tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malicious_Software_Removal_Tool) without any positives.

The last time this happend, maybe a month ago, I've rebooted my system and I guess this (temporarily) solved the issue. Just to appear now again.

Having multiple other EC2 AWS Windows 2016 servers, and dozens of other Windows servers to administer for years, I *never* came across such a weird behavior.

#### My question

Does anyone have a clue what might go on on this server and how to resolve this?

#### Update 1

It seems that this first occurred after an automatic daylight-saving time switch (the server and time zone is in Germany).

Some of the tasks had this message as the "Last Run Result":

> The operator or administrator has refused the request. (0x800710E0)

In German:

> Die Anforderung wurde vom Operator oder Administrator zurückgewiesen. (0x800710E0)

All suggestions I found about this error (like e.g. [this one](https://www.mcseboard.de/topic/220111-aufgabenplanung-0x800710e0/)) was to edit and store tasks again. I'll try this now.

#### Update 2

The scheduled tasks again did not run and I found multiple entries like the following in the Event Log:

> The system time has changed to ‎2022‎-‎03‎-‎20T01:25:40.348000000Z from ‎2022‎-‎02‎-‎16T14:47:49.130142400Z.
>
> Change Reason: An application or system component changed the time.

So it was changed to one month in the future.

And later, it was changed back to the correct date again:

> The system time has changed to ‎2022‎-‎02‎-‎16T12:04:30.541000000Z from ‎2022‎-‎03‎-‎20T01:37:24.558311600Z.
>
> Change Reason: An application or system component changed the time.

So this changed the date one month into the future and back again. It seems this is enough to confuse my tasks enough to not run ever again.

I still don't know the reason.

One suggestion I found regarding these Event Log entries was to [re-register the time service](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/00345979-c6dd-4a37-aba6-dddef147d054/find-out-which-program-changed-system-clock?forum=win10itprogeneral):

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
```

Since the server runs on EC2 at Amazon, AWS, I'll not try [this command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/windows-set-time.html):

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:169.254.169.123 /syncfromflags:manual /update
```

And also this command:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation" /v RealTimeIsUniversal /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f
```

Then, to make the Scheduled Tasks run again, I'll open each one and save it again.

#### Update 3

We've now experienced time changes again, following is what the audit log entries look like.

First, the change was 133 days into the future:

[image]

The selected entry at "17.03.22 06:47:44" has these details:

> A new process has been created.
>
> Creator Subject:
> Security ID:        SYSTEM
> Account Name:       EC2AMAZ-K5BI954$
> Account Domain:     WORKGROUP
> Logon ID:       0x3E7
>
> Target Subject:
> Security ID:        NULL SID
> Account Name:       -
> Account Domain:     -
> Logon ID:       0x0
>
> Process Information:
> New Process ID:     0x3478
> New Process Name:   C:\Windows\System32\conhost.exe
> Token Elevation Type:   %%1936
> Mandatory Label:        Mandatory Label\System Mandatory Level
> Creator Process ID: 0x44bc
> Creator Process Name:   C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
> Process Command Line:   **??\C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe 0xffffffff -ForceV1**
>
> Token Elevation Type indicates the type of token that was assigned to the new process in accordance with User Account Control policy.
>
> Type 1 is a full token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.  A full token is only used if User Account Control is disabled or if the user is the built-in Administrator account or a service account.
>
> Type 2 is an elevated token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.  An elevated token is used when User Account Control is enabled and the user chooses to start the program using Run as administrator.  An elevated token is also used when an application is configured to always require administrative privilege or to always require maximum privilege, and the user is a member of the Administrators group.
>
> Type 3 is a limited token with administrative privileges removed and administrative groups disabled.  The limited token is used when User Account Control is enabled, the application does not require administrative privilege, and the user does not choose to start the program using Run as administrator.

And the first entry at the new (wrong) date in the future "28.07.22 13:52:50" was:

> A new process has been created.
>
> Creator Subject:
> Security ID:        SYSTEM
> Account Name:       EC2AMAZ-K5BI954$
> Account Domain:     WORKGROUP
> Logon ID:       0x3E7
>
> Target Subject:
> Security ID:        NULL SID
> Account Name:       -
> Account Domain:     -
> Logon ID:       0x0
>
> Process Information:
> New Process ID:     0x1f64
> New Process Name:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe
> Token Elevation Type:   %%1936
> Mandatory Label:        Mandatory Label\System Mandatory Level
> Creator Process ID: 0x4a8
> Creator Process Name:   C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
> Process Command Line:   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe" /ua /installsource scheduler

I've [googled for](https://www.google.com/search?q=conhost.exe%20%22ForceV1%22) the "??\C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe 0xffffffff -ForceV1" and found several articles that claim that this *might* be malicious:

- [Who left the backdoor open? Using StartupInfo for the win](https://www.trustedsec.com/blog/who-left-the-backdoor-open-using-startupinfo-for-the-win/)
- [What is the effect of the arguments in the following: conhost.exe 0xffffffff -ForceV1](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/198816/826)

The system time was later automatically set back by the system:

[image]

In fact it was first changed back too much to 16.03.2022 and right after that to the correct time 17.03.2022 again.

The details of the entry looks like:

> The system time was changed.
>
> Subject:
> Security ID:        LOCAL SERVICE
> Account Name:       LOCAL SERVICE
> Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
> Logon ID:       0x3E5
>
> Process Information:
> Process ID: 0x4a0
> Name:       C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
>
> Previous Time:        ‎2022‎-‎07‎-‎28T11:59:14.787568600Z
> New Time:     ‎2022‎-‎03‎-‎16T15:02:28.443000000Z
>
> This event is generated when the system time is changed. It is normal for the Windows Time Service, which runs with System privilege, to change the system time on a regular basis. Other system time changes may be indicative of attempts to tamper with the computer.

So now, even after I've activated audit, I'm still completely confused about what is happening on my system.

#### Update 4

*(April 2022)*

We finally gave up and set up another AWS EC2 machine, this time a Windows Server 2022.

I migrated everything manually from the old server to the new server (files, databases, IIS websites, etc.).

It is running since approx. 2 weeks now without any issues.

While this is not a technical solution, it is at least a working one.

#### Update 5

*(July 2022)*

Everything is still working correctly on the new server, I hope it stays this way.

Comment: Can you please run `get-hotfix -Id KB4583458` in a powershell and show the output?

Comment: Thanks, @GeraldSchneider, it prints "`Cannot find the requested hotfix on the 'localhost' computer.`". [See screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/oci0FH7.png).

Comment: MRT will not provide anything that your usual EDR app can provide. If there is a process that changes the system time 32 days in the future, then changes it back 12 minutes later, you need to enable process and command line auditing so you can identify the offending process. These events are easy to identify on systems that are properly configured, and not identifiable on systems that are not properly configured.

Comment: Thanks, @GregAskew I've followed [this guide](https://www.itprotoday.com/strategy/understanding-and-enabling-command-line-auditing), then issued a `gpupdate` command line command and rebooted my server. Hope this will log enough details when this occurs again.

Comment: Just posted an update, @GregAskew. Although I've activated the audit as you recommended, I've still no clue what is going on (and no clue on how to fix it, either) 

Comment: You may want to enable time service debug logging. If it is associated with a resync, it may appear in that log. If a process is setting the time, it should appear in command line auditing entries, or you may need to install SysInternals SysMon and enable process  logging.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/turn-on-debug-logging-in-windows-time-service

Comment: Possibly, the upstream NTP server is messing up. I'd run a packet capture (with *ntp* filter) just to be sure, and try another server like `ptbtime1.ptb.de` (since you're in Germany ;-).

Comment: @uwekeim is the issue solved? if yes please remind to answer the question and accept it 24h later - (sonst bleibt bis zum Ende des Universum erhalten)

Comment: Ha ne, ned solved, Siehe mein "Update 4" oben in meiner Frage. Das kann ich nicht als Antwort posten. Some things are meant to be unsolved 

Comment: @UweKeim We've had a similiar problem once. It was hard to figure it out, but it was simple caused by an application, whos developer messed up timezone handling. Rather than converting times and calculating dates, he was modifying the system clock back and forth. We then ran that application with an account without the permissions to modify the system time and it was resolved. So, be aware, you might have migrated the trouble maker as well 